# Cairo: Draw an array of pixels

Tags: cairo

I'm just starting to explore Cairo, but right now I really want to use it for something very simple.

I have a very low-tech bitmap, i.e., a 3*X*Y array of numbers.  I'd like to use Cairo to make this into a bitmap and write to a file.  I'm looking through tutorials and I'm not seeing a way to use it for comparatively low-level functions like this.

I don't *think* I need guidance on how to use the tool once I know what the tool is.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't actually test this, but the following should give you lots of useful hints:

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define WIDTH 42
#define HEIGHT 42
uint8_t data[WIDTH][HEIGHT][3];

cairo_surface_t* convert()
{
    cairo_surface_t *result;
    unsigned char *current_row;
    int stride;

    result = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    if (cairo_surface_status(result) != CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        return result;

    cairo_surface_flush(result);
    current_row = cairo_image_surface_get_data(result);
    stride = cairo_image_surface_get_stride(result);
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        uint32_t *row = (void *) current_row;
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            uint32_t r = data[x][y][0];
            uint32_t g = data[x][y][1];
            uint32_t b = data[x][y][2];
            row[x] = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        }

        current_row += stride;
    }
    cairo_surface_mark_dirty(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Where is the snippet from? Is it part of a tutorial?

Comment: I do not remember where this is from, but I guess I wrote it myself.